# progress bar update issue,directly change from 0 to 100,there's not 1,2,3...... in Java

Tags: multithreading, user-interface, progress-bar

I want to change a progress bar use SetValue(int),but it doesn't work,it always change directly from 0 to 100 when progress finish.I try to create a new thread to invoke "setValue(int)",instead of invoking form UI thread,but it's still not worked.

`my code:`

```
public class UpdateProgressBar extends Thread{
public UpdateProgressBar(javax.swing.JProgressBar progressBar){
    this.progressBar = progressBar;
}
public void update(){
    for(int i = 1; i <= 100; i++){
         progressBar.setValue(i);
        try {
            sleep(10);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(UpdateProgressBar.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }         
}   
private javax.swing.JProgressBar progressBar;
}
```

,progressBar is defined in UI thread,then I `UpdateProgressBar upb = new UpdateProgressBar(progressBar);` in UI thread and invoke it's update way`upb.update();`did I make some mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although you have declared `UpdateProgressBar` to extend `Thread` you are not actually running it as a separate thread. You need to call `start()` to make the new thread actually run. If you call `upb.update()` from the event dispatch thread then you are executing that method *on* the event dispatch thread.

You want this in your client code:

```
UpdateProgressBar upb = new UpdateProgressBar(progressBar);
upb.start();
```

and change your `UpdateProgressBar` class to this:

```
public class UpdateProgressBar extends Thread{
    public UpdateProgressBar(javax.swing.JProgressBar progressBar){
        this.progressBar = progressBar;
    }

    @Override
    public void run(){
        for(int i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
            final int j = i;
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    progressBar.setValue(j);
                }
            });
            try {
                sleep(10);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(UpdateProgressBar.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
    }
    private javax.swing.JProgressBar progressBar;
}
```

You need to have the `SwingUtilities.invokeLater` because Swing components are not thread-safe. You also need the nasty `final int j = i` because of Java's less-than-brilliant handling of closures. Putting your code into the `run` method means it will be executed when you call `Thread.start()`.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the Maximum value set for it is 1? Set the progress bar's maximum before you start setting the value and see what happens.